# Replicate selected postgresql tables between two servers?

Tags: postgresql, replication, rsync, failover

What would be the best way to replicate individual DB tables from a Master postgresql server to a slave machine? It can be done with cron+rsync, or with whatever postgresql might have build in, or some sort of OSS tool, but so far the postgres docs don't seem to cover *how* to do table replication. I'm not able to do a full DB replication because some tables have license->IP stuff connected to it, and I can't replicate those on the slave machine. I don't need instant replication, hourly would be acceptable as well.

If I need to just rsync, can someone help identify what files within the /var/lib/pgsql directory would need to be synced, or how I would know what tables they are.

Comment: You can simply use `CREATE PUBLICATION mypub FOR ALL TABLES`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get anything useful by copying individual tables files in the data directory. If you want to replicate selected tables, there are a number of good options.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Postgres 10, logical replication is built into Postgres! This is often a better solution than external solutions. [The Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logical-replication.html) are great and easy to follow. It's very easy. See the [quick setup docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logical-replication-quick-setup.html), which in essense boils down to running this:

```
-- On publisher DB
CREATE PUBLICATION mypub FOR TABLE users, departments;

-- On subscriber DB
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION mysub CONNECTION 'dbname=foo host=bar user=repuser' PUBLICATION mypub;
```

Comment: (posting on this old question as it's a top Google result)

Comment: For anyone curious, we've used this in production (tables with many millions of rows, lots of inserts/updates) and it works beautifully with low latency.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try Bucardo, which is an open source software to synchronize rows between tables even if they are in a remote location. It's a very simple software, and it is capable of creating one-way synchronization relationships as well.

Check out http://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo